# Best practice to report errors in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, crashlytics

I'm trying to use [firebase_crashlytics](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_crashlytics) lib with my Flutter project, the problem is that Flutter never crashes, I can throw exceptions in the code, but all exceptions in dart are considered non-fatal exceptions. Those will be reported normally to the console, but I wanted Flutter, native, and unhandled exceptions to be considered fatal exceptions.

I wanted one of the following:

- Crash the app when I have an unexpected exception (close the app with "not responding")
- Report fatal exception to firebase console
- A work around?

My main.dart code:

```
Future main() async {
  runZoned<Future<void>>(() async {
    await DotEnv().load('.env');
    setupNotifications();
    FlutterError.onError = Crashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
    runApp(MyApp());
  }, onError: Crashlytics.instance.recordError);
}
```

What I already tried to do:

- `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');` It works, but not really user friendly
- Call kotlin function that tried to crash the app via `MethodChannel`, didn't work.

Things I could probably do:

- Call a `toast` to notify the user that something went wrong
- Show a pop-up notifying the user that something went wrong and close the app
- Just close the app
- Try to load the initial state of the application main screen

Comment: It might be worth explaining WHY you are trying to achieve such behavior, given that the default behavior is preferred by everyone. A non-fatal exception, even if unhandled, is something that the app might be able to recover from, while a fatal exception is something that the app cannot recover from and is therefore worse user experience. You also cannot force Firebase to report those as fatal exceptions, because they aren't. You can indeed do all the things you've listed under "Things I could probably do", but they are not within the scope of this question. The "best" practice is the default.

Comment: Even if it's and non-fatal exception it can cause app breaking problems like interfaces not loading correctly, buttons not doing anything, etc. While those will be considered "non-fatal" by flutter, it's definately something that will make the user feel the changes, so which is the best way to notify them something went wrong? And why can't we separate our own already know and handled exceptions from more grave, unknown unhandled exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is the default behavior for Crashlytics on Flutter, at least for now. If you want to exit your app I can recommend you the following options:

1. Navigate to an error screen, showing a generic error message using `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil()`. then when the user clicks `OK` or after a timer, you exit the app. In order to exit the App you can throw and exception on the native side or use `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');` although your App might be blocked at the App Store, as Apple rejects programatically exits.
2. Be careful to have an error screen, with a friendly error message, ready for each possible error, so the user won't have to exit the app.